# ¿subir una web a wordpress vacío solo con el backup?

Tags: wordpress

Bien, hice un backup con el plugin backup de wordpress de la web en el servidor anterior, el inconveniente aqui es, que no tengo acceso al antiguo servidor, por ese motivo es que quiero migrarla.
he buscado maneras de hacerlo y lo mas viable parecia ser duplicator, esto me arroja un error, entonces.
¿como logro migrar una web en wordpress, solo con su backup?

Comment: Depende de cómo se hizo el respaldo, hay varios plugins para eso. Abre el archivo en un editor de texto, probablemente incluya algún comentario/indicación.

Comment: Bueno te comento, al no tener acceso al servidor anterior, hice un backup..con el plugin de wordpress y tambien me tome el trabajo de hacerlo con el plugin de duplicator.. pero resulta que cuando le doy en el browser a el nombre de la pagina/installer.php , me arroja un not found.. entonces me quede trabada en eso,,

Comment: De todos los [plugins para respaldo de wordpress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/backup/) que hay ¿Cómo podemos saber cuál usaste?